# .FIND not finding the date

Tags: excel, vba

vartype(Date_var)  is 8 which is Vbstring. vbtype of Newsheet.Range("B5") is 7 which is vbdate and the values are as follows. Date_var = 20211207,Newsheet.Range("B5") =  07/12/2021 and after numberformat it is converted to 20211207. Though the date is present, .Find is unable to get the column number. I tried converting date_var to Cdate and I am getting Type mismatch. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    Date_var = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("AF1:AL1000").Cells(1, 4).Value
    
    If Date_var = "" And Lastrow = 1 Then
       Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With Newsheet.Range("B5:BL5")
       .NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"
        Set Columnfind = .Find(What:=Date_var, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, 
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Columnfind Is Nothing Then
           colnum = 0
        Else
           colnum = Columnfind.Column
      End If
     
    End With
```

Comment: Setting the `NumberFormat` only changes what is displayed. `Find` searches the values, not the displayed text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the values and types of the data you are looking for and the data in the search area, then convert the data you are looking for, if necessary. In the first option, data of different types is searched, and `Date` (consider the locale) is not found. In the second variant `Date` is converted to `String` (consider the locale) and the search is successful.

**Option 1**

```
Sub test1()
    Date_vars_array = Array(20211207#, 20211207, "20211207", #12/7/2021#)   ' or #7/12/2021# for your locale
    
    For Each Date_var In Date_vars_array
        With NewSheet.Range("B5:BL5")
            .NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"
            Set Columnfind = .Find(What:=Date_var, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Columnfind Is Nothing Then
               colnum = 0
            Else
                 colnum = Columnfind.Column
            End If
        End With
        Debug.Print ".Finding for 'Date_var = " & Date_var & "' which has '" & TypeName(Date_var) & "' data type:"
        Debug.Print vbTab & "'NewSheet.Range(""B5"") = " & NewSheet.Range("B5").Value & "' and has '" & TypeName(NewSheet.Range("B5").Value) & "' data type"
        Debug.Print vbTab & "'colnum = " & colnum & "'" & vbLf
    Next
End Sub
```

**Output 1**

```
.Finding for 'Date_var = 20211207' which has 'Double' data type:
    'NewSheet.Range("B5") = 07.12.2021' and has 'Date' data type
    'colnum = 2'

.Finding for 'Date_var = 20211207' which has 'Long' data type:
    'NewSheet.Range("B5") = 07.12.2021' and has 'Date' data type
    'colnum = 2'

.Finding for 'Date_var = 20211207' which has 'String' data type:
    'NewSheet.Range("B5") = 07.12.2021' and has 'Date' data type
    'colnum = 2'

.Finding for 'Date_var = 07.12.2021' which has 'Date' data type:
    'NewSheet.Range("B5") = 07.12.2021' and has 'Date' data type
    'colnum = 0'
```

**Option 2** (If TypeName(Date_var) = "Date" Then Date_var = Format(Date_var, "yyyymmdd") added)

```
Sub test1()
    Date_vars_array = Array(20211207#, 20211207, "20211207", #12/7/2021#)   ' or #7/12/2021# for your locale
    
    For Each Date_var In Date_vars_array
        With NewSheet.Range("B5:BL5")
            .NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"
            
            If TypeName(Date_var) = "Date" Then Date_var = Format(Date_var, "yyyymmdd")
            
            Set Columnfind = .Find(What:=Date_var, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Columnfind Is Nothing Then
               colnum = 0
            Else
                 colnum = Columnfind.Column
            End If
        End With
        Debug.Print ".Finding for 'Date_var = " & Date_var & "' which has '" & TypeName(Date_var) & "' data type:"
        Debug.Print vbTab & "'NewSheet.Range(""B5"") = " & NewSheet.Range("B5").Value & "' and has '" & TypeName(NewSheet.Range("B5").Value) & "' data type"
        Debug.Print vbTab & "'colnum = " & colnum & "'" & vbLf
    Next
End Sub
```

**Output 2**

```
.Finding for 'Date_var = 20211207' which has 'Double' data type:
    'NewSheet.Range("B5") = 07.12.2021' and has 'Date' data type
    'colnum = 2'

.Finding for 'Date_var = 20211207' which has 'Long' data type:
    'NewSheet.Range("B5") = 07.12.2021' and has 'Date' data type
    'colnum = 2'

.Finding for 'Date_var = 20211207' which has 'String' data type:
    'NewSheet.Range("B5") = 07.12.2021' and has 'Date' data type
    'colnum = 2'

.Finding for 'Date_var = 20211207' which has 'String' data type:
    'NewSheet.Range("B5") = 07.12.2021' and has 'Date' data type
    'colnum = 2'
```

[image]

*Side note: Find searches text*
[image]